# Does 1 Thessalonians 5:10 rule out annihilism?

Tags: death, 1-thessalonians, afterlife

An annihilist would affirm that "those who sleep" equals "those who die" and that those who die are both dead physically and non-existent as to consciousness.  As I understand the position, an individual who dies in this life literally ceases to exist up until God resurrects the body and recreates the soul of that individual at the judgement.  [Here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=annihilationist) is a list of related questions and answers that flesh out what annihilationism proposes.

1 Thessalonians 5:10 says this:

> Who died for us, that, whether we wake or sleep, we should live together with him.

And it is obvious from context that "sleep" here is being used as a metaphor for death as opposed to "dullness of senses" as it is in verses 6-7:

> Therefore let us not sleep, as do others; but let us watch and be sober. For they that sleep sleep in the night; and they that be drunken are drunken in the night.

Those who are "awake" and are "of the day" are not to sleep in this sense.  Therefore, verse 10 appears to say that "whether we wake (live) or sleep (die) we should/may/will live with him who died for us.

Does this verse rule out the annihilist take on "sleep"?

Comment: @Lesley It is not my position but the position of annihilationism as I understand it.  Some of the questions and answers that are linked in OP indicate it is believed (by annihilationists) that when a person dies the animating spirit returns to God, the inanimate body goes in the ground, and the soul/consciousness ceases to exist.

Comment: @Nigel Perhaps reconstitute was a poor word choice.  I have edited in recreate instead as it is probably closer to what annihilationism beleives.

Comment: @MikeBorden I've deleted the comment. I read it again and I think I misunderstood.

Comment: @MikeBorden - Thanks for explaining and I have also deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Those who do not believe in soul annihilation at physical death happily agree with annihilists that "sleep" in 1 Thess. 5:10 refers to the death of a person. There is no problem seeing the biblical use of "sleep" with regard to people dying. When a person dies physically, their physical body is said to be "asleep", awaiting the time of the resurrection of the body.

That, however, in no way contributes to the notion of total oblivion - non-existence in any form - of the person who has died.

Indeed, the text itself shows that even though the body is "asleep" in death, the person continues to live with Christ! Physical death does not stop the person who has lived for Christ (while alive in the body) from continuing to live with Christ in the spirit. Were the person annihilated, they could not live together with Christ after death.

This is confirmed by Paul who ends his letter to the Thessalonians with this doxology, which shows the spirit and the soul must exist equally, as does the body, being preserved, not annihilated:

> "And the very God of peace sanctify you wholly; and your whole spirit
> and soul and body be preserved blameless unto the coming of our Lord
> Jesus Christ" (1 Thess. 5:23).

Of course, annihilists would interpret those verses very differently, but the fact that the verses are open to different interpretations shows that they cannot be used to "rule out annihilism" (as your question asks) any more than they can be used to "rule in anti-annihilism". One interpretation cancels the other out, which is why proof-texts are always insufficient. The whole body of biblical teaching on the subject must be incorporated.

However, when the one verse you mention is read in conjunction with the last verse in Paul's letter, it should be clear that he was not teaching any annihilation of the spirit and the soul, because he believed in the preservation of spirit and soul. Yes, he believed those Christians alive back then could still be alive at the coming of their Lord Jesus Christ, but he also believed that those who had died physically would be 'ahead' of living Christians, with their bodies being resurrected before those still alive would also be caught up to join Christ, see ch.2 vs.19, ch.4 vss.13-17 & 2 Thess. 2:1-2 & 2 Cor. 5:1-8.

Again, annihilists would interpret all those verses in harmony with their belief in annihilation of spirit and soul at death, so there's just no point in picking one proof-text and asking if it "rules out" any particular belief, or not. However, **my answer to your question is that *1 Thess.5:10 does not rule annihilism out, but, because of verse 23 and many other writings of Paul, it certainly does*.**

Answer (score 2):

- “*whether we wake or sleep*”: All saved Christians, whether alive or dead at the time of Christ's return.
- “*let us not sleep*”: Hope that Christ will return during their own lifetimes.
- “*let us watch and be sober*”: Hope that they will be prepared at the time of his return.

This is simply a continuation of what was stated in the previous chapter about the two states of Christians that will be part of the first resurrection:

> For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so God will bring with Him **those who sleep** in Jesus.
> For this we say to you by the word of the Lord, that **we who are alive and remain until the coming** of the Lord will by no means precede **those who are asleep**.
> For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of an archangel, and with the trumpet of God.
> And **the dead in Christ** will rise first.
> Then **we who are alive** and remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air. And thus we shall always be with the Lord.
> **Therefore comfort one another with these words.**
> — 1 Thessalonians 4:14–18

Comment: If God is bringing with Him those who sleep in Jesus then they must exist.  Doesn't this also disprove what annihilationists claim about the non-existent consciousness of the dead?

Comment: @MikeBorden - according to BDAG, the verb "ago" in 1 Thess 4:14 means "to direct the movement of an object from one position to another".  Now, if you believe that the saints are already in heaven and have received their reward, what functions does the resurrection serve?  If the saints are already enjoying heaven, why do they even need a body?

Comment: @Dottard I would think they need a new body to interact with the new physical creation.  They are in God's presence but incomplete until the redemption of the body, which all creation waits and groans after.

Comment: @MikeBorden, [Some people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_who_awoke_from_a_coma#:~:text=Annie%20Shapiro%20(1913%2D2003),like%20state%20and%20woken%20up.) have remained in a coma for up to 30 years, with no brain activity.  Where were those people during this time? Isn't that question just as meaningless as *Where are those that sleep while awaiting the resurrection?*?

Comment: I don't know if it's meaningless to ask whether they are somewhere or they are nowhere.